# Could not Send SMS to mobiles with mobile numbers fetched from database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, sms

This is my code which is used to send SMS. I could send sms to multiple numbers but when I select one number SMS is not send. So I put an if else condition to check if there is only one number selected, then it should not have comma else it should seperate with commas. but now SMS is not sending to any numbers. What could have gone wrong. Please help me.

```
      $college = $this->input->post('college'); 
      $count = count($college); 
      if($count == 1){
 $mobiles = implode("" , $_POST['college']);
} else {
$mobiles = implode("," , $_POST['college']);
 }  
$data = array(
          'sms_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
          'sender' => 'Some Addresss',
          'receiver' => $mobiles,
          'sms_message' => $this->input->post('message')
    );       
 function curl($url)
  {
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
 $data = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 return $data;
 }
   //$mobile = $mobiles; 
    $username = "*****"; //your username
    $password = "*****"; //your password
    $sender = "****"; //Your senderid
    $username = urlencode($username);
    $password = urlencode($password);
     $sender = urlencode($sender);
     $messagecontent = $this->input->post('message'); //Type Of Your Message
   $message = urlencode($messagecontent); 
   $url="http://****.com/sendsms?uname=".$username."&pwd=".$password."&senderid=".$sender."&to=".$mobiles."&msg=".$message."&route=T";
  $response = curl($url);
```

Comment: make sure that college is not a empty array

Comment: before calling curl() function .just echo the url echo $url;  exit; and see everything populated correctly or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created but not used the `$college` variable.  Change this:

```
if($count == 1){
   $mobiles = implode("" , $college);
} else {
  $mobiles = implode("," , $college);
}
```

to this:

```
if($count == 1){
   $mobiles = implode("" , $_POST['college']);
} else {
  $mobiles = implode("," , $_POST['college']);
}
```

Also, if that was really your password, you should change it. :)